# MongoDB Aggregation based on userID and time period

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to achieve something like

```
{ _id: "A", count: 2 }
{ _id: "B", count: 1 }
```

from

```
{ userId: "A", timeStamp: "12:30PM" } <- start of 5 min interval A: 1
{ userId: "B", timeStamp: "12:30PM" } <- start of 5 min interval B: 1
{ userId: "B", timeStamp: "12:31PM" } <- ignored
{ userId: "A", timeStamp: "12:32PM" } <- ignored
{ userId: "B", timeStamp: "12:33PM" } <- ignored
{ userId: "A", timeStamp: "12:37PM" } <- start of next 5 min A : 2
```

where it groups based on userId and then after userId is group, the count is triggered every 5 mins.

For example: Within any 5 min period, starting at say midnight, an unlimited number of collections can have a timeStamp from 00:00 to 00:05 but would only be counted as 1 hit.

Hopefully I am explaining this clearly.

I'm able to group by userId and get the count in general but setting a condition of the count seems to be tricky.

Comment: Can you explain the count  ? What is your condition for your expected json ?

Comment: @Veeram count will be registered for any records that take place between 00:00 and 00:05. If multiple records are found for that userId within that 5 min time period, the count will still only be one. This logic is aggregated across all time periods: 00:00 - 00:05, 00:05 - 00:10, 00:10 - 00:15, etc

Comment: @Jeff Why in your example the result is B=2? Shouldn't it be 1? Since the timestamps of B are all in the same 5 minutes period.

Comment: @AchiEven-dar you are right, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) and `$addToSet` - the drawback is that you have to specify all the ranges manually:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$timeStamp",
      boundaries: [ "12:30PM", "12:35PM", "12:40PM", "12:45PM", "12:50PM", "12:55PM", "13:00PM" ],
      output: {
        "users" : { $addToSet: "$userId" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$users"
  },
  {
    $group: { _id: "$users", count: { $sum: 1 } }
  }
])
```

Comment: boundaries can be programmatically generated too

Comment: @AshokMandal obviously, I meant you can't pass start, end and step but you have to generate that long array :)

Comment: @mickl i tried the above code with 2 dates to test and received the following error: $switch could not find a matching branch for an input, and no default was specified."

Comment: @Jeff you need at least 3 values which defines two buckets, try `boundaries: [ "12:30PM", "12:35PM", "12:40PM" ]`

Comment: @mickl i tried 3, same issue. I believe this is because the date is actually of type "String" like "2018-03-01T08:00:22.000Z"

Comment: @Jeff for sure, I've tested on your example so you should redefine your bucket boundaries to get this working

Comment: @Jeff please note that we're not specifying default bucket so you should  remember that `first_boundary <= all_your_items <= last_boundary`

Answer (score 1):

Micki's solution is better if you have mongo 3.6.
If you have mongo 3.4 you can use $switch. 
Obviously you would need to add all the cases in the day.

```
db.getCollection('user_timestamps').aggregate(
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$userId',
        timeStamp: {$push: '$timeStamp'}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        timeStamps: {
            $map: {
                input: '$timeStamp',
                as: 'timeStamp',
                in: {
                     $switch: {
                        branches: [
                            {
                                case: {
                                    $and: [
                                        {$gte: ['$$timeStamp', '12:30PM']},
                                        {$lt: ['$$timeStamp', '12:35PM']}
                                    ]
                                },
                                then: 1
                             },
                             {
                                case: {
                                    $and: [
                                        {$gte: ['$$timeStamp', '12:35PM']},
                                        {$lt: ['$$timeStamp', '12:40PM']}
                                    ]
                                },
                                then: 2
                             }
                        ],
                        default: 0
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $unwind: '$timeStamps'
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        count: {
            $addToSet: '$timeStamps'
        }

    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: true,
        count: {$size: '$count'}
    }
}
)
```

If you don't have mongo 3.4 you can replace the $switch with

```
cond: [
   {
       $and: [
           {$gte: ['$$timeStamp', '12:30PM']},
           {$lt: ['$$timeStamp', '12:35PM']}
       ]
   },
   1,
   {
       cond: [
           {
               $and: [
                   {$gte: ['$$timeStamp', '12:35PM']},
                   {$lt: ['$$timeStamp', '12:40PM']}
               ]
           },
           2,
           0
       ]
   }
]
```